# Migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016 directly?

Tags: 2010, migration, 2016

Is there a way to migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016 directly without intermediate SharePoint 2013 server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to migrate to 2013 first. The only ways to do it directly ie skipping 2013 is by doing it manually or by using some third party tool or building a tool by yourself.

See this official Microsoft [Post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2015/05/12/whats-new-in-sharepoint-server-2016-installation-and-deployment/)

Extract from above Post.

> **Upgrade and Migration**
>
> SharePoint Server 2016 will support upgrade from
> SharePoint Server 2013.  To upgrade from SharePoint Server 2013 to
> SharePoint Server 2016, you can use the database-attach method to
> upgrade. In the database-attach method, you first create and configure
> a SharePoint Server 2016 farm. Then you copy the content and service
> application databases from the SharePoint Server 2013 farm, and then
> attach and upgrade the databases.  This upgrades the data to the new
> version.
>
> NOTE Site collections provisioned in backward compatible SharePoint
> 2010 (14) mode, must be upgraded to 2013 prior to upgrading to
> SharePoint Server 2016.  For additional information on upgrading site
> collections to SharePoint 2013

See this for other details about [migrating to 2016](https://unnieayilliath.com/2016/07/17/sharepoint-2016-migration/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for migrating the content databases, you can use SharePoint 2013 Foundation to attach the DBs from SP2010.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with above suggestions, there is no direct upgrade method from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016 using the standard tools. A double-hop jump, from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and then onto SharePoint 2016, may make sense or use a third party SharePoint migration tool to migrate directly from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016. you should also check this [article](http://www.topsharepoint.com/content-migration-tools-for-sharepoint).